# how to get data based on a correlated table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Listings table
+------------+---------+
| name       | id      |
+------------+---------+
| Example 1  |  1      |
| Example 2  |  2      |
| Example 3  |  3      |
| Example 4  |  4      |
| Example 5  |  5      |
| Example 6  |  6      |
+------------+---------+

Categories table
+------------+---------+
| name       | id      |
+------------+---------+
| Catname 1  |  1      |
| Catname 2  |  2      |
| Catname 3  |  3      |
+------------+---------+

ListingCats table
+--------+---------+
| cat_id | list_id |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       |
| 1      | 2       |
| 1      | 3       |
| 2      | 1       |
| 3      | 1       |
| 3      | 3       |
| 2      | 2       |
| 1      | 5       |
| 2      | 6       |
+--------+---------+
```

I am trying to build 2 queries which should be simple.

The first thing needed is to get a count of how many listings in the listings table corelate to a given category ID in the listingcats table.

The second part is getting all of the data (*) in the rows from the listings table that corelate to the given category id in the listingcats table.

I have tried a number of joins and for some reason none want to work properly. Can anyone help based on the example tables given above please. The 'given' category ID in this case would be '1'.

Comment: Can you add the queries that you have made so far?

Comment: from the example data you've posted, what output would you expect?

Comment: Those are not difficult joins, post your attempts, it will be something 'silly'

Comment: Only the 2nd query looks like it even requires a join. I think your first query is just select cat_id, count(*) from listingcats group by cat_id

Comment: Brian: you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first query, you can use a simple join, and return a count

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
FROM Listings l
JOIN ListingCats lc ON l.id = lc.cat_id
WHERE lc.cat_id = 1
```

This will return all rows from the listings table such that the listings id has a corresponding cat_id in the listingcats table, but exclusive to those that have a cat_id of 1. Then, the count aggregate function returns the number of rows.

For the second one, you can just use the same subquery above, but without the aggregate function, and select all values.

```
SELECT * FROM Listings l
JOIN ListingCats lc ON l.id = lc.cat_id
WHERE lc.cat_id = 1
```

Try those, please let me know if they work or not and I will try to work through them more with you.

**EDIT**

After looking back at the question, if you are given a specific cat_id you don't even need to use a join, you can simply query the listings table for one that has that id. If the given id is one:

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
FROM Listings l
WHERE l.id = 1
```

And then again, even more broad for the second one:

```
SELECT * FROM Listings l WHERE l.id = 1
```

Comment: I actually had to change it just a little, but it works. The change was ON l.id = lc.list_id

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were looking for the cat_id. Glad you were able to make it work though!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE  `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE  `listings_cats` (
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `list_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(lc.list_id) as the_count 
FROM categories c 
JOIN listings_cats lc ON (lc.cat_id = c.id) 
GROUP BY c.id;

SELECT l.id, l.name, c.name AS category_name 
FROM listings l JOIN listings_cats lc ON (lc.list_id = l.id) 
JOIN categories c ON (lc.cat_id = c.id);
```